# How to access Laravel Forge provisioned server

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I'm trying to push a Laravel installation from development to a live-environment on a Laravel Forge-server. When pushing, I'm getting an error, that I'm not getting on my local environment.

I can't figure out, how I connect directly to the provisioned server (through FTP or SFTP), to change single files manually (to debug).

Which means that in order to try something, then I need to make a new commit and an entirely new deployment, for every thing I want to test. Quite tedious and it clutters my git history!

... I can't even do a `commit --amend`, since that gives me the error:

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

---

**Attempt 1)** I can't find anything about it in the [Forge knowledge base](https://forge.helpscoutdocs.com/search?query=FTP).

**Attempt 2)** I've found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834518/laravel-forge-digitalocean-adding-a-sftp-user-with-restricted-access-only-to) [articles](https://laravel-news.com/setup-sftp-forge-provisioned-server) [talking](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/granting-access-to-forge-site-folder-to-additional-sftp-user) [about](https://laravel.io/forum/06-26-2014-how-to-set-up-an-ftp-server-on-a-forge-provision-server) [a](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/create-ftp-user-and-limit-access-to-specific-sites) good guide, but that guide gives an error 404: 
It's this one: https://freek.dev/2016/03/let-your-clients-use-sftp-on-a-forge-provisioned-server/

Am I missing something obvious? Or is the commit-n-push really the way to go? Is this normal for automated deployment systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who find this question, then Forge-support got back to me really quickly and linked to this blogpost, [explaining how to get sftp-access to a Forge-provisioned server](https://blog.laravel.com/forge-connect-to-your-server-using-ssh-or-sftp)

What I did wrong, was that I didn't use the username: `forge` (I was using my email).